# LimeSurvey - Uploading a PDF

Tags: pdf, upload, survey, limesurvey

I've been using LimeSurvey to create a survey. There is a question type called File Upload that allows a user to upload a file instead of answering a question. As far as I can tell, the question type does not allow the user to upload a PDF. Is anyone aware of a workaround for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Its mostly you do not have the directories "upload" and "tmp" with write permissions. Make this necessary change and it should all be fine.

amit

Comment: I tried it. It did not work. I am receiving the same error. Also, to clarify, I am updating the template.css file

Answer (score 1):

If you click on the 'advanced settings' for the file upload question, there's an entry for file type that's just a comma-separated list of extensions to allow.